# I need to build a trigger to perform a complicated insert task

Tags: sql-server

edit-This is expanded from the original question.

I need a trigger to send certain information to a table to be transferred to another group.  However only a certain class of data determined by C4 on T2 has to be transferred when updated.

```
create trigger Trig on T2
after Insert, update, delete
if update(C3) --DETERMINES THAT RECORD HAS BEEN UPDATED IN A MANNER THAT NEEDS TO BE  
              TRANSFERRED     
begin
if C4 != 9 return --DETERMINES IF RECORD NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED
else
insert P1 --BEGINS PUTTING INFORMATION INTO THE ABLE THAT IS TRANSFERRED
(C1, C2, C3)
select T1.C2, T1.C3, T2.C3 --INFORMATION THAT NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.C1 = T2.C2 --T1.C1 IS A UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY THAT CONNECTS ROW IN T1 TO ROW
                      IN T2
END
GO
```

This is the full test code. The actual code will involve more columns of different names.  all table data types are the same.
Thanks.

Comment: IN SQL Server, you aslo need to be aware that trigger work on bathces of data, so youmust wirte the other stuffin your trigger to deal with multiple records in inserted or deleted. If you are setting anything to a scalar varaible, your trigger will likely not work if mulitple rcords are inserted/updated/deleted. Alsways test a trigger with multiple records in the batch as well as single records.

Comment: fortunately only one record is ever inserted or updated at a time.

Comment: you cannot make that assumption in a trigger. There will be times when multiple records are inserted from somewhere other than your application. It is irresponsible to assume only one record. You can create a horrible data integrity mess if you do not consider multiple record inserts!

Comment: It is also an extremly poor practice to use implied joins (and you are joining on the wrong thing as you need to use the inserted table not the base table).  Why are you using something replaced 20 years ago with a better technique. Would you do that with C#code (if it was that old)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create trigger Trig on T2
after insert, update, delete
as
 -- So that @@rowcount does not get affected by trigger code
    set NoCount on
 -- If c3 column participated in update (it most certainly did in insert)
    if update(C3)
    begin
     -- Insert or update triggered this operation
        if exists (select *
                     from Inserted)
        begin
            insert into P1 (C1, C2, C3)
            select T1.C2, T1.C3, T2.C3 --INFORMATION THAT NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED
            from T1
         -- Inserted is a pseudotable holding inserted/updated data
            inner join inserted T2
            on T1.C1 = T2.C2
            where T2.C4 <> 9 --DETERMINES IF RECORD NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED
        end
        else
     -- Separate insert for deleted records
     -- To simplify inserting additional info for deleted records only
        begin
            insert into P1 (C1, C2, C3)
            select T1.C2, T1.C3, T2.C3 --INFORMATION THAT NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED
            from T1
         -- deleted is a pseudotable holding deleted/updated data
            inner join deleted T2
            on T1.C1 = T2.C2
            where T2.C4 <> 9 --DETERMINES IF RECORD NEEDS TO BE TRANSFERRED
        end
    end
```

Comment: I do need to transfer records deleted.  one of the fields inserted into the new table will have 'deleted' entered as it's value so the receivers of table P1 will have the same record deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `INSERTED` table in your trigger to get the value of your `c4` column but if you could give us more information about the problem you are trying to solve, perhaps we can suggest a better alternative than triggers.

[Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

> DML trigger statements use two special tables: the deleted table and
>   the inserted tables. SQL Server automatically creates and manages
>   these tables. You can use these temporary, memory-resident tables to
>   test the effects of certain data modifications and to set conditions
>   for DML trigger actions. You cannot directly modify the data in the
>   tables or perform data definition language (DDL) operations on the
>   tables, such as CREATE INDEX.
>
> In DML triggers, the inserted and deleted tables are primarily used to
>   perform the following:
>
> - Extend referential integrity between tables.
> - Insert or update data in base tables underlying a view.
> - Test for errors and take action based on the error.
> - Find the difference between the state of a table before and after a data modification and take actions based on that difference.

Comment: I added full trigger purpose to the post.  Thank you for the assistance.